# Intercepting ribbon connector

Tags: soldering, connector, header

I recently obtained an electric typewriter and am trying to intercept the keyboard circuitry for an arduino project. The keyboard has a 17 pin ribbon cable that goes into a plastic connector on the main board. The holes are too small to fit any wires through and my soldering skills are not good enough to attach any wires to the solder points. The holes are a pretty standard spacing, and seem to line up spacing wise with the headers on my arduino.

My thought is I can solder a strip of header onto the board and just set the ribbon connector into the header. That doesn't solve my problem though, because I still can't connect extra wires to it. What I need is some kind of header strip that has an extra row of connectors to tap into the main set, or something like that.

Has anyone done anything similar to this, or have any tips, or know a part that may help me.

Comment: Can you give pictures and measurements, even a ruler can be pretty helpful if it is .1 inch spacing or not.

Comment: Seconding the call for pictures; if this is a standard ribbon cable you can probably just add an IDC connector.

Comment: ok, I'll get pictures on when I get home tonight. But it is .1" spacing

Comment: Standard ribbon cable is 0.050" spacing

Answer (score 4):

You may use an new IDE connector and attach it on the ribbon cable (I'm supposing they are using the standard size of wires). This way you can create a derivation without damaging the cable.

[image: Ribbon Cable Connector]

Another good practice is to use a buffer for all the pins. I know its a bit costly but otherwise the input impedance could cause interference in the system.

Comment: This is so simple and effective I never would have thought of it.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on how to crimp these connectors: http://hubbard.engr.scu.edu/embedded/guide/ribbon/

Comment: sorry, maybe ribbon cable is the wrong word. It is a thin sheet of plastic with tiny flat contacts running through it.

Comment: @captncraig: Do you mean a [flat-flexible cable (FFC)](http://www.parlex.com/products/ffc.php)?